# handle error on Microsoft.AnalysisServices update method

Tags: c#, sql-server, error-handling, ssis, ssas

I am updating dimension definition in 'Data Source View'. Doing it using C# code inside SSIS script task.
Here is simplified C# code:

```
DataSourceView ASDataSourceView;
//DataSourceView inherits from MajorObject
ASDataSourceView.Schema.Tables["DimTable"].ExtendedProperties["QueryDefinition"] = "SELECT * FROM ufc.TableWithData";
ASDataSourceView.Update();
```

I need to handle error which may appear during Update() method. 
I thought that usual approach with try catch will work but it seems it is not a case. 
I need to get an xml response object somehow and then check if it is empty(no error) or parse it and build further logic.

I was trying to read Microsoft documentation but have no idea how to do it.
[XmlaWarningCollection Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.analysisservices.xmlawarningcollection?view=sqlserver-2016)

When I run update xml statement in SSMS I get the following messages: 
when update succeed:

```
<return xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-analysis">
  <root xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-analysis:empty" />
</return>
```

when update fails(fails because of syntax error not logic which is also not very correct from simulation point of view):

> XML parsing failed at line 9597, column 63: The name in the end tag of the element must match the element type in the start tag.
>   Run complete

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 2):

I think I finally found solution:

First you need to enable CaptureXML option;

```
ServerName.CaptureXml = true;
```

Second run Update with XmlaResultCollection option:

```
UpdateOptions uo = default(UpdateOptions);
UpdateMode om = default(UpdateMode);
XmlaWarningCollection xm = null;
ASDataSourceView.Update(uo, om, xm);
```

Third you execute update statement:

```
XmlaResultCollection resultCollection = ServerName.ExecuteCaptureLog(false, false);
```

After that I was able to parse **resultCollection** object:

```
String ErrorMessages = String.Empty;

if (resultCollection.ContainsErrors) {
                ErrorMessages += $"Errors occured in cube {ConnectionString.CatalogName}:" + Environment.NewLine;
                foreach (AS.XmlaResult result in resultCol) {
                    foreach (object error in result.Messages) {
                        if (error.GetType() == typeof(AS.XmlaError))
                            ErrorMessages += "ERR: " + ((AS.XmlaError)error).Description + Environment.NewLine;
                        else if (error.GetType() == typeof(AS.XmlaWarning))
                            ErrorMessages += "WARN: " + ((AS.XmlaWarning)error).Description + Environment.NewLine;
                    }
                }
                throw new Exception(ErrorMessages);
            }
```